# Quartz.NET scheduling

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am new to this Quartz.NET thing and I have some questions about it cause it don't seem to work as I want to.

**Question 1:** I am defining simple `IJobDetail` and `ITrigger`. **[SOLVED]**

```js
NameValueCollection config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("quartz") as NameValueCollection;
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory(config);
            IScheduler scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();

            try
            {            
                scheduler.Start();              

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJobTestScheduling>()
                    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .Build();

                DateTimeOffset endDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
                
                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .WithRepeatCount(2))
                    .EndAt(endDate)
                    .Build();
                
                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);             
             
            }
            catch(SchedulerException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se);
            }
            finally
            {
                scheduler.Shutdown();
            }
```

**HelloJobTestScheduling**

```js
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;

            JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

            string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\dejan;Initial Catalog=QuartzTest;Integrated Security=True";

            string query = "INSERT INTO test (id, datetime) " +
                   "VALUES (@id, @datetime) ";

            // create connection and command
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
            {
                // define parameters and their values
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "1";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@datetime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

                // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
            
        }
```

**App.config**

```js
<section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  
  <quartz>
      <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="MyScheduler" />
      <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="AUTO" />
      <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
      
      <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz"/>
      <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="30"/>
     
      <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
      <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
      <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Data Source=localhost\dejan;Initial Catalog=QuartzTest;Integrated Security=True" />
      <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
      <add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="false" />
      <!--<add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />-->
      <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
      <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
      <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="false" />
    </quartz>
```

What this job actually does in reality is this: inserting only one row in the database, and after that it won't do anything. It waits to the `.endAt` and shows in console that the scheduler is closed. What is wrong with my code?

***Note***: I have all the required database tables for the scheduler to work in the background.

**Question 2:** Why this CRON is not recognized?
`.WithCronSchedule("0 1 0 ? * ?")`

Visual Studio error says: 
`'?' can only be specified for Day-of-Month -OR- Day-of-Week.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron expressions in Quartz.Net are made up of 7 [sub-expressions](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html):

1. Seconds
2. Minutes
3. Hours
4. Day-of-Month
5. Month
6. Day-of-Week
7. Year **(optional field)**

The last one is optional. 
Your **cron** expression is not valid.
If you want to run to execute something every minute the right one is: `0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *`

I would advice you to use this [tool](http://www.cronmaker.com/) to generate your cron expressions.
It's easier.

Comment: What is confusing to me is that all of that examples on Quartz.NET site have 6 sub-expressions, and the 7th is noted as an option. Why there are codes with 6 sub-expressions as an example, if that doesn't work?

Comment: Updated my answer. Actually the last parameter is optional. Your cron expression is not valid.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I didn't had the `*` on the optional `Year` field. That was the actual problem, I thought because it is optional I don't really have to put any sign there.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1** is solved. Just a short note, my mistake was that I close the scheduler too early in `finally`. If I comment that lane, everything works good.

But, I still **need help about Question 2**.